# \begin{align*} and \end{align*} syntax problem

Tags: alignment

```
\newpage
        \item % Question 1) 3.4.5
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item % Question (a)
                    \begin{align}
                        \textbf{u} = [4,1,-5] \\
                        \textbf{v} = [3,-1,-5]
                    \end{align}

                    \begin{align*}
                        &\textbf{u} \times \textbf{v} \\ 
                        &= [4,1,-5] \times [3,-1,-5] \\ 
                        &= 
                            \begin{vmatrix}
                                i & j & k \\
                                4 & 1 & -5 \\
                                3 & -1 & -5 \\ 
                            \end{vmatrix}
                        &= [(1)(-5) - (-5)(3), (4)(-5) - (-5)(3), (4)(-1) - (1)(3)] \\ 
                        &= [(-5) - (-15), (-20) - (-15), (-4) - (3)] \\
                        &= [-20, -5, -7] \\

                    \end{align*}


                \item % Question (b)
            \end{enumerate}
        \item % Question 2) 3.4.7
```

I'm getting a runaway argument/missing $ or } problem but I haven't been able to identify what the problem is. I noticed that when I took out the align completely, it works. Does anyone know what could be wrong with my syntax here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Remove or comment out  the empty line in the `align` environment.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and the welcomes! I found out that it ended up being that empty line, would've never thought. I'm not sure what a Minimal Working Example is though, could you expand on that to understand for future reference in other questions? Thanks again.

Comment: Put briefly, a minimal working example (MWE) is the smallest complete document that reproduces the problem. It should contain all necessary packages and definitions required to run the example, but nothing more than that. Creating an MWE might take some work/trial and error, but it will also help isolate and identify the problem. There is more info in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but it can help someone ...

- your problem is already soled by @leandriis comment
- what is MWE (Minimal Working Example) is explained in @Torbjørn T. comment
- here is an example of MWE, what we ask you to provide instead of code fragment. See comments in it!

```
\documentclass{article} % we need to know which document class you use
\usepackage{amsmath}    % pacake which is necessary for compilation of MWE

\begin{document}
%   \newpage            % haven't any influence on your problem, let be omitted
\begin{enumerate}       % is missing in your code fragment. Maybe it is itemize?
                        % Since it is irrelevant to your problem can be removed
    \item % Question 1) 3.4.5
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item % Question (a)
                \begin{align}
                    \textbf{u} & = [4,1,-5] \\  % corect is `mathbf{u}
                    \textbf{v} & = [3,-1,-5]    % corect is `mathbf{v}
                \end{align}
                \begin{align*}
                \textbf{u} \times \textbf{v}  % before this line you have &, 
                                              % it cause ugly 'align' formatting,
                                              % so I remove it and preserve them 
                                              % only before sign 'equal'
                    &= [4,1,-5] \times [3,-1,-5] \\
                    &=  \begin{vmatrix}
                            i & j & k   \\
                            4 & 1 & -5  \\
                            3 & -1 & -5
                        \end{vmatrix}           \\
                    &= [(1)(-5) - (-5)(3), (4)(-5) - (-5)(3), (4)(-1) - (1)(3)] \\
                    &= [(-5) - (-15), (-20) - (-15), (-4) - (3)] \\
                    &= [-20, -5, -7]    % in your fragmen here follows empy line,  now is removed
                \end{align*}

            \item % Question (b)
        \end{enumerate}
    \item % Question 2) 3.4.7
\end{enumerate} %  closing list in the first level
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

however, I wonder if you might looking for something like this:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,
            blkarray}  % new
\usepackage{enumitem}  % new
\setlist[1]{label=\bf\thesubsection.\arabic*}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}       % added, demonstrate design of document
\subsection{Subsection} % added, demonstrate design of document
    \begin{enumerate}
\item here is probably is some text/explanation of tasks
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item % Question (a)
            \begin{align}
                \mathbf{u} & = [4,1,-5] \\
                \mathbf{v} & = [3,-1,-5]
            \end{align}
            \begin{align*}
            \mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v}
                & =[4,1,-5] \times [3,-1,-5] \\
                & = \begin{blockarray}{*{4}{>{\scriptstyle}c}}  % instead of your 'vmatrix'
                                                                % it enable to write indices outside of matrix
                        & i & j & k   \\
                    \noalign{\setcounter{BAenumi}{1}}
                        \begin{block}{>{\scriptstyle\theBAenumi}r [*{3}{>{\normalsize}c}]}
                        & 4 & 1 & -5  \\
                        & 3 & -1 & -5 \\
                        \end{block}
                    \end{blockarray}           \\
                &= [(1)(-5) - (-5)(3),\, (4)(-5) - (-5)(3),\, (4)(-1) - (1)(3)] \\
                &= [(-5) - (-15),\, (-20) - (-15),\, (-4) - (3)] \\
                &= [-20, -5, -7] \\
            \end{align*}

        \item % Question (b)
    \end{enumerate}
\item here is probably is some text/explanation of the next tasks
    \end{enumerate}
\subsection{Subsection}
    \begin{enumerate}
\item next tasks
\item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Teepeemm, good point. I add comment to code about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
  \newpage
   \LARGE
    \section{ Question (1) 3.4.5}

           \subsection {Question (a)}
             \hspace{4cm}   \begin{tabular}{rc}
                    \textbf{u} =& $\left[4\;,\; 1,-5 \right] $\\
                    \textbf{v} =& $\left[3,-1,-5 \right]
                    $% Ihave used /; to get the spaing
                \end{tabular}
       \vspace{1cm}         

       \hspace{2cm}  \begin{tabular}{rc}
                    & $\textbf{u} \times \textbf{v}$ \\ 
                    =& $\left[4,1,-5\right] \times \left[[3,-1,-5\right]$ \\ 
                    &\\
                    =& \begin{tabular}{|ccc|} 
                            i & j & k \\
                            4 & 1 & -5 \\
                            3 & -1 & -5 \\ 
                        \end{tabular}
                        \end{tabular}\\

                        \vspace{1cm}

                        \begin{tabular}{rl}
                    &= $\left[[(1)(-5) - (-5)(3), (4)(-5) - (-5)(3), (4)(-1) - 
                    (1)(3)\right]$ \\ 
                    &= $\left[(-5) - (-15), (-20) - (-15), (-4) - (3)\right]$]  
                    \\
                    &= $\left[[-20, -5, -7\right]$\\

                \end{tabular}


            \subsection{  Question (b)}

          \section{ Question 2) 3.4.7}




         \end{document}
```

I have used standard latex commands and no packages. I thought that this is what you wanted. Please feel free to send your comment/ I have used \LARGE. This you can remove to get the standard output.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what was wrong in the OP, and how you fixed it?